# Passing selected string from dropdown to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I am displaying a dropdown list from my controller as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var title = new List<String>()
        {
            "English", "French", "Spanish"
        };
        List<SelectListItem> languageList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string defaultTitle = "Language";
        foreach (var item in title)
        {
            languageList.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = item,
                Value = item,
                Selected = (item == defaultTitle ? true : false)
            });
        }
        ViewBag.LanguageList = languageList;

        return View();
    }
```

My View is as follows:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("GetStatusTrad", "StatusTradController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Translation</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Language")
            @Html.DropDownList("lang", new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList, "Text", "Value"), "Language")
        </div>
    </div>

        <div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

}
```

It displays the dropdown correctly, but when I want to pass the selected value to an action of the controller, I get a 404 error.

My action is :

```
public ActionResult GetStatusTrad(string language)
    {
      *some code*
    }
```

Any idea why I can't pass the selected value of the dropdown to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList("lang", new SelectList(...` generates a `<select>` with `name="lang`. You need to change the parameter in the POST method to match

```
public ActionResult GetStatusTrad(string lang)
```

As a side note, `LanguageList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so using `new SelectList()` to create another identical one is pointless. I can be just

```
@Html.DropDownList("lang", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LanguageList, "Language")
```

You also have a typo in the `BeginForm()` method. It needs to be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetStatusTrad", "StatusTrad", FormMethod.Post))
```

i.e. `"StatusTrad"`, not `"StatusTradController"` (unless you have really named your controller `StatusTradControllerController`)

Comment: What? Of course it will (and I assume you have marked that method with `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`)

Comment: And `"StatusTradController"` should be `"StatusTrad"` in the `BeginForm()` method (unless your controller is really named `StatusTradControllerController`)

Comment: Yes I did but changing the the parameter to ''lang'' does not work.  The submit button does not hit the method.

Comment: Read my previous comments!

Answer (score 2):

Your helper should be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("language", <-- note this
 new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList, "Text", "Value"), "Language")
```

It happend becose basically your helper will be rendered to input like this:

```
<select name="language">
...
</select>
```

And on `form` POST your controller will be able to bind your values based on `name` property of input.

Answer (score 1):

you can use strongly type view to return selected dropdown value.

create simple class like below

```
public class myModel
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Then use this class/model in **View**

```
@model yourProject.Models.myModel
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Language</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.language)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.language, new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList, "Text", "Value"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller method look like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetStatusTrad(myModel model)
{
  *some code*
}
```